# PHP - 1 form, 2 tables - Can't insert data into table 1

Tags: php, mysql, forms, html-table

I'm trying to make an invoice system that adds rows, from a tutorial and data is correctly inserted into tbl_orderdetail, but I can't make it work to insert data to tbl_order.

These are the 2 MYSQL tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_order` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`re_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`locat⁮ion` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_orderdetail` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`order_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`product_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`quantity` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`price` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`discount` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`amount` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=73 ;
```

And this is my connection code:

```
<?php
$cn = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
if($cn)
{
mysql_select_db('mydb',$cn);
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
$re_name = $_POST['re_name'];
$location = $_POST['location'];
{
mysql_query ("INSERT INTO tbl_order(re_name,location)        VALUES('{$_POST['re_name']}','{$_POST['location']}')");
$id = mysql_insert_id();
for($i = 0 ;$i < count($_POST['productname']);$i++)
{
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_orderdetail 
                SET order_id        = '{$id}', 
                    product_name    = '{$_POST['productname'][$i]}', 
                    quantity        = '{$_POST['quantity'][$i]}', 
                    price           = '{$_POST['price'][$i]}', 
                    discount        = '{$_POST['discount'][$i]}', 
                    amount          = '{$_POST['amount'][$i]}'
                ");
}
}
?>
```

What is wrong in my code?

Here is the form that submits the values:

```
<form  action="" method="post"> 
<div class="box-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                ReceptName
                <input type="text" name="re_name" id="re_name" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                Location
                <input type="text" name="location" id="location" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" id="submit" value="Save Record">
    </div>

        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
                <th>No</th>
                <th>ProductName</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Discount</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th><input type="button" value="+" id="add" class="btn btn-primary"></th>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="detail">
                <tr>
                    <td class="no">1</td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control productname" name="productname[]"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control quantity" name="quantity[]"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control price" name="price[]"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control discount" name="discount[]"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control amount" name="amount[]"></td>
                    <td><a href="#" class="remove">Delete</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>

            <tfoot>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th style="text-align:center;" class="total">0</th>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>      
          </div><!-- /.box -->
          </form> 
        </div><!--/.col (left) -->
```

Comment: What errors have occurred? Also you need to format your code.

Comment: There are no written errors, but the only table that gets my inputs is  tbl_orderdetail. Table tbl_order is always empty.

Comment: Is error reporting enabled?

Comment: Yes, they are, @Script47

Comment: Trying debugging using Chrome Logger. You can print out values on your chrome console

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `mysql_query() or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: Plus, I don't see an opening form tag here so we don't know if you're using the right method etc.

Comment: Thanks, @Fred-ii-, but no errors were displayed. I also added the opening form tag. The php connection code is in the same page. Tha's why there is no action. I tryed action="nameofpage.php", but it didn't solve it too.

Comment: These are the exact form tags I'm using.

Comment: @Mimispo read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/14110189#14110189 it explains why you shouldn't use MySQL.

Comment: Thank you, @Script47. I will read. But This tutorial uses mysql and my wamp uses php 5.3

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for helping me.
I dropped tbl_order and created a new one called 'orcamen'.

Here's the php code that worked:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$razao     = $_POST["razao"];
$local      = $_POST["local"];
$condicao     = $_POST["condicao"];
$estado         = $_POST["estado"];
$material       = $_POST["material"];
$obs        = $_POST["obs"];
mysql_query
("INSERT INTO orcamen ( id , razao , local , condicao , estado , material , obs ) 
        VALUES ( NULL , '$razao', '$local', '$condicao', '$estado', $material', '$obs')");
$id = mysql_insert_id();
for($i = 0 ;$i < count($_POST['productname']);$i++)
{
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_orderdetail 
                SET order_id        = '{$id}', 
                    product_name    = '{$_POST['productname'][$i]}', 
                    quantity        = '{$_POST['quantity'][$i]}', 
                    price           = '{$_POST['price'][$i]}', 
                    discount        = '{$_POST['discount'][$i]}', 
                    amount          = '{$_POST['amount'][$i]}'
                ");
}
}
```